# How to open mailto link in Chrome with Window.open without creating a new tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension and am trying to open a custom url scheme with (window.open) without having a new blank tab open up. For sake of argument lets try the 'mailto' url scheme.

My code:

```
window.open("mailto://Bob Lawblah", '_self');
```

Unfortunately this open up a new blank tab as well as opening up the default mail program even though I specified '_self'. According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) I don't seem to be anything wrong.

Any ideas on how to not have an extra tab open when opening a 'mailto' link?

Comment: To be clear: regardless of what the URL is I still cannot open the page in the current tab. Example: 

    window.open("http://www.google.com", '_self');

does not respond. Though if I take out the '_self' part it opens up the window just fine in a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a chrome extension, there's a different frame of reference for what _self and other targets mean. Instead of trying to use mailto, how about sending them to a site's "Contact Me" page?

I think this offers easier usability for the end user. Honestly, I don't have a default mail application, even if I did have outlook or some dedicated application, I wouldn't use it because GMail is just awesome (personal preference, but I bet I'm not alone). For example, I use an extension to change all mailto links to open GMail so I can email somebody through it. My extensions won't modify your extensions javascript or mailto links (part of the sandboxing).

With a "Contact Me" page, you can not only hide your email address, but allow people to contact you on your terms (no attachments, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the response but it isn't the 'mailto' URL I would like to open. I have registered a custom url scheme on my machine and would like to open that up. Mailto was just an example. Basically it should be able to open any custom url (ex. myapp://something). Just like iTunes is something like: (itms://urltoapp)

Comment: ah. I'm glad to see more people are making use of that. I'll keep looking into it. I've tried a lot of things... a down and dirty alternative is you open a page that loads your custom link and then closes itself, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in a Chrome Extension context, you should be using `chrome.tabs` APIs. If you have an extra tab floating around, you can just close it via http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-remove