# mailto link (in chrome) is triggering window.onbeforeunload - can i prevent this?

Tags: javascript, mailto, onbeforeunload

Possibly related to [How to open mailto link in Chrome with Window.open without creating a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098852/how-to-open-mailto-link-in-chrome-with-window-open-without-creating-a-new-tab)

Hi all.  I have a form page where i've put a window.onbeforeunload confirm, to stop people navigating away and losing their changes by accident:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  if(changed)
    return "You have unsaved changes.  Do you really want to leave this page without saving?";
};
```

where `changed` is a variable i set to true whenever the user makes any changes.  That's all fine.  However, i've also added some mailto links to the page, like so:

```
<a class="button button-alt" href="mailto:foo@foo.com">Report a problem</a>
```

Even though the mailto isn't navigating away from the page (it's opening the users default mail app), it's still triggering the onbeforeunload event, prompting the confirm box, which is annoying.  I can get round it setting `target="_blank"` on the link, but then the user is left sitting in an empty tab.

Can i set the mailto link to not trigger the onbeforeunload event?  I thought of a horribly hacky way of doing it by having another temporary javascript variable which causes the onbeforeunload confirm to not trigger, but it seems kind of dirty. I'll do it anyway while i wait for a response but does anyone have a nicer solution?

thanks, max

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Building off of epascarello's solution, the following JQuery code should do the trick:

```
    var ignore_onbeforeunload = false;
    $('a[href^=mailto]').on('click',function(){
        ignore_onbeforeunload = true;
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        if (!ignore_onbeforeunload){
            return "Halt! you are not supposed to leave!";
        }
        ignore_onbeforeunload = false;
    };
```

Comment: Really? you answer a post 3 years later? lol Only difference is adding the onclick with an unobtrusive event...lol

Comment: Relies on jQuery for no reason, relies on global variable. John Kurlak's answer below is much nicer. It uses a hidden iframe, totally removing the need for JavaScript, let alone jQuery. Can then self-contain the fix in the template file.

Comment: What about browsers who don't call `onbeforeunload` on click of such link? Seems like closing will be skipped in this case.

Comment: The question was how to avoid degrading the experience when it is triggered. When it's not supported is exactly the desired experience.

Answer (score 29):

A really simple fix to this is to do something like this:

```
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com" target="hidden-iframe">Email me</a>
<iframe name="hidden-iframe" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;"></iframe>
```

(And of course, move the styles to their own stylesheet instead of inlining them.)

Comment: I'm late to the party but just came across this same issue. This is by far the better solution. The others rely on lots of ugly JavaScript/jQuery. This way you can self-contain the fix within the html template, using zero JavaScript.

Comment: @Oranges13: Sure it does.  What version are you using?

Comment: This was working for me in Chrome until I added "frame-src" CSP which broke it

Comment: Thanks @JohnKurlak This is an awesome solution. This is just a late response from someone that just benefited from this old post. Thank you.

Comment: this is the fix for Blazor applications experiencing a disconnect issue with 'tel:' links for example too

Answer (score 5):

Add a flag and see if it is flipped, set the flag on the link click.

```
var ignore = false
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (changed && !ignore) {
        return "You have unsaved changes.  Do you really want to leave this page without saving?";
    } else {
        ignore = false;
    }
}
```

And the link

```
<a class="button button-alt" href="mailto:foo@foo.com" onclick="ignore=true">Report a problem</a>
```

It would be better to add the onclick with JavaScript code.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, what about browsers who don't call `onbeforeunload` on click of such link? Seems like closing will be skipped in this case.

Comment: @epascarello what is the changed variable? (line 3)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this problem inside the onbeforeunload event by checking event.target. This way you dont have to use outer variables or any extra bindings.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {

    var activeElement = $(event.target.activeElement);
    // console.log('onbeforeunload', activeElement);

    var isMailto = activeElement && activeElement.is('[href^=mailto:]');
    var isTel = activeElement && activeElement.is('[href^=tel:]');

    if(!isMailto && !isTel) {
        // logic when link is "normal"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, also a bit hacky but a bit more generic way to make the beforeunload ignore certain types of links:

In the beforeunload, inspect the link that caused the beforeunload, and if it is not a http or https link, don't bother the user.

Unfortunately it is not easy to inspect the link that caused the beforeunload, so this is where it gets a little hacky with an onclick handler and global variable.

```
var lastClicked = null;
window.onclick = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    lastClicked = e.target
}
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    if (changed && lastClicked && lastClicked.href 
        && lastClicked.href.substring(0,4) == 'http')
        return "You have unsaved changes";
}
```

Edit: Almost forgot, this answer comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12065766/421243

Answer (score 2):

Some other solution with pure JS and using the focused element:

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
  const isMailTo = document.activeElement.protocol === "mailto:";

  if (!isMailTo) {
    // do your stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [John Kurlak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29016818/9266823) answer, you can simply use :

```html
<a href="mailto:foo@bar.com" target="_blank">Email me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Theiaz answer, you can add a Boolean global var as `protectUnload` followed by a regexp to allow all external protocols except links ( http(s) ):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    return (protectUnload && (typeof document.activeElement.protocol !== "undefined" && /^http(s)?:$/.test(document.activeElement.protocol))) || null; // return null == no confirm
};
```

It does not prevent for being kick out from the page using `location.href` but for in that case you can add 1 more boolean to the formula to always be protected for unloading the page (setting it to `true` before `location.href`'s new value).

Comment: Adding boolean global variables is usually not the strongest answer. Containing your JS to an IIFE or similarly scoped properties is the right way. The other answers in this nearly 9 year old post handle the question well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the target of the anchor to a hidden iframe burried in the page. `<a href="mailto:x@y.com" target="hiddenIframe"`.

If the mailto is called via a javascript function (from a button or anchor or whatever) you could even create the iframe on the fly, set its src to the mailto, then remove it in a timeout.

Either way, the current page is not affected, and no need for pop-up tabs or windows.