# stop redirecting page if it is redirecting by clicking on anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent page redirecting I know it can be achieve by this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "Dude, are you sure you want to leave? Think of the kittens!";
}
```

which was answered here [Prevent any form of page refresh using jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript)

But in my case I only want to prevent page when it is redirecting by clicking on any of the anchor tag.

Also `event.preventDefault()` will not work in my case while clicking on anchor tag because all anchors are not redirecting page so it should work fine.

I only want to stop redirecting page if it is redirecting by clicking on anchor. Any solution?

Comment: Set a flag when an anchor is clicked. Then check that flag in this handler

Comment: You can look at the `.caller`

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333498/determine-calling-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep a flag which tells you whether or not the user clicked an `a` tag, then read that on your `onbeforeunload` script:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (_clickedAnchor) {
        _clickedAnchor = false;
        return "Dude, are you sure you want to leave? Think of the kittens!";
    }
}

_clickedAnchor = false;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("a").click(function () {
        _clickedAnchor = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't even think of this. Awesome answer

Comment: What if a link is used to call JS? This flag would be set.

Comment: @Diodeus Maybe links that redirect instead of just do javascript can have a different class, then it's just a matter of changing the selector - like `jQuery("a.redirect-link")`.

Comment: Or kind of a hacky way: `jQuery("a").click(function () { _clickedAnchor = true; setTimeout(function() {_clickedAnchor = false; },100);});`

Comment: I would, personally, avoid JQuery for something this small/simple and perhaps do something more similar to suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12065766/624590

Comment: @DRobinson If you already weren't using jQuery, you're probably right, but the question was tagged with it - if you're using jQuery, then I say just use it wherever you can. So much easier than dealing with browser-specific event quirks.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so (re: JQuery)

Comment: @DRobinson Tabbing to a link and hitting enter still fires the `click` event.

Comment: Eek yes, that it does!

Comment: Then, yeah, the only issue I see is as Diodeus explained. You can store the href in _clickedAnchor and check whether it's null, or starts with a "#", instead of true/false. Set it to null where you'd typically set it to false. Still not perfect because it could very well have an href w/ code that catches the click and returns false to keep it from redirecting.

Comment: @JoeEnos Thanks, Really very nice solution, it was beyond my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onhashchange`.

With jQuery:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    alert('bye byee?');
});
```

Plain DOM JavaScript:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    alert('bye byee?');
};
```

**Note:** You will need to create a custom "hash-change" handler for older browser which don't support this event.

You can easly do this with `setInterval` and detect any changes in `document.location.hash`.

---

Failsafe `onhashchange` for older browsers:

```
var currentHash = document.location.hash;

window.prototype.onhashchange = function( callback ) {
    if(typeof(callback) == 'function') {
        setInterval(function() {
            if(document.location.hash !== currentHash) {
                callback();
            }
        }, 650); // more than a half-a-second delay
    }
}
```

And you can use it as an event in regular DOM convention.

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7 and IE 9 but it does not work, will try this callback

Answer (score 0):

So since you tagged jQuery I'll put my solution in terms of that. You can grab all the a tags and then check to make sure the anchor is a redirect, then use the `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    if ($(this).attr('href') != window.location.href)
    {
       e.preventDefault();
       //do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The caller will be null if a link is clicked:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert(window.onbeforeunload.caller)    
}
```

Comment: It returns null all the time even i refresh page from url

Comment: But if you refresh it from a JS function, you should get the function name.