# How to prevent `tel:` links from firing a `beforeunload` event?

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling, dom-events, page-refresh

I have a popup appear before the user refreshes the page by doing this:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

This is working as expected, but I don't want the popup to appear after the user clicks a `tel:` link, like `<a href="tel:123123123">phone number</a>` for example.

I was thinking I could detect a click on all the `tel:` links like so:

```
const phoneLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="tel:"]');
phoneLinks.forEach((phoneLink) => {
  phoneLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Not sure what I can do
  });
});
```

I have a codepen set up for this, but I'm not sure how to actually solve the problem: https://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/XWxYJQG

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9740510/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `target` attribute to the links, so they open in a new window.

```
phoneLinks.forEach(link => link.addAttribute('target', '_blank'))
```

Comment: This is a great idea! Is there a way to do this so that a new tab or window is not opened?

Comment: No, that's the whole point. It has to open a new window so it doesn't try to replace the current window, which is the problem you're trying to solve.